# addeventlistener doesn't work as expected

Tags: javascript

I have put the code on codepen on the bottom;, thank you!

I wrote  a javascript calendar, but when I use addEventListener, it causes some problems, 
here is the code, Thank you for help!

```
  document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function(){
var today = new Date(),
    year = today.getFullYear(),
    month = today.getMonth(),
    monthTag =["Jan","Feb","Mar","Apr","May","Jun","Jul","Aug","Sep","Oct","Nov","Dec"],
    day = today.getDate();

function Calendar(selector) {
    this.el = document.getElementById(selector);
    this.draw();
}

Calendar.prototype.draw  = function() {
    var that = this,
        reset = document.getElementById('reset'),
        pre = document.getElementsByClassName('pre-button'),
        next = document.getElementsByClassName('next-button');

        pre[0].addEventListener('click', function(){that.preMonth(); });
        next[0].addEventListener('click', function(){that.nextMonth(); });
        reset.addEventListener('click', function(){that.reset(); });
    this.drawHeader();
    this.drawDays();
};

Calendar.prototype.drawHeader = function() {
    var headDay = document.getElementsByClassName('head-day'),
        headMonth = document.getElementsByClassName('head-month');

        headDay[0].innerHTML = day;
        headMonth[0].innerHTML = monthTag[month] +" - " + year;

    console.log('hello')
 };

Calendar.prototype.drawDays = function() {
    var days = document.getElementsByTagName('td'),
        startDay = new Date(year, month, 1).getDay(),
        nDays = new Date(year, month + 1, 0).getDate(),
        n = startDay;
    for(var k = 0; k <42; k++) {
        days[k].innerHTML = '';
        days[k].className = '';
    }
    for(var i  = 1; i <= nDays ; i++) {
        days[n].innerHTML = i; 
        n++;
    }
    for(var j = 0; j < 42; j++) {
        if(days[j].innerHTML === ""){
            days[j].className = "disabled";
            a = j;
        }
        if((j === day + a)&&((month===today.getMonth())&&(year===today.getFullYear()))){
            days[j].className = "today";
        }
    }
};

Calendar.prototype.preMonth = function() {
    if(month < 1){ 
        month = 11;
        year = year - 1; 
    }else{
        month = month - 1;
    }
    current = false;
    this.drawHeader();
    this.drawDays();
};

Calendar.prototype.nextMonth = function() {
    if(month >= 11){
        month = 0;
        year =  year + 1; 
    }else{
        month = month + 1;
    }
    this.draw();
}; 

 Calendar.prototype.reset = function() {
     month = today.getMonth();
     year = today.getFullYear();
     this.draw();
 }

var calendar = new Calendar('#calendar');
}, false);
```

As you can see, the `preMonth()` works fine, but the `nextMonth()` works wrong if I change `{this.drawHeaders(); this.drawdays}` to `{this.draw();};`

**this  is the code on codepen; when you click right button above 2 times; date display isn't as expected!** 
http://codepen.io/puny-d/pen/eygIH

Comment: Could you give us some more detail about how it "works wrong"? What output are you getting?

Comment: and where are those other two methods defined?

Comment: *"As you can see, the preMonth() works right"* How am I supposed to see that if I can't run the code?

Comment: side note- code like this is why jQuery was created

Comment: *"date display isn't as expected!"* Again: What do you expect and what is the result you get? How should we know if what we see isn't what you expect if we don't know what you expect?

Comment: I am sorry that I didn't express explicitly, so I put it on the code pen; when you click right img on the calendar header, the time display   is right, it should be the next month

Comment: It wouldn't be too difficult to say "clicking the next month bottom as second time changes the month from July to October".

Comment: I am sorry! So could you explain problems to me? Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each click on the prev / next buttons adds new event handlers. The event handlers call `draw`, which binds event handlers again. So after the second click of the next button, you are performing `month = month + 1` **twice**.

**Solution:** Only bind the event handlers *once* when you create the calendar.

Comment: Again, Thank you very much.I have learned javascript for just 2 month, So I don't understand event handlers; Maybe I should read more about it! Whatever you did good jobs! Sorry for my bad expression at first

Comment: This might help to get a better understanding of event handlers: http://www.quirksmode.org/js/introevents.html